# Using fetchone() only inputs first row into MySQL then closes

Tags: python, mysql, database-cursor

My code finishes with exit code 0 but only updates the first row, I'm doing something wrong when trying to update it, but can't figure it out. I'm quite the novice.

```
import pymysql
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

mainDB_cnx = pymysql.connect(user='', password='',
                             host='',
                             database='Content', use_unicode=True, charset="utf8mb4")
mainDB_cursor = mainDB_cnx.cursor()

mainDB_cursor.execute("SELECT content_url FROM Content.Reddit")
row = mainDB_cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    print(row[0])
    open_page = driver.get(row[0])
    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.decompose()
    content_names = soup.get_text()
    with mainDB_cnx:
        mainDB_cursor.execute("""
            UPDATE Content.Reddit
            SET artists_names_2 = %s
            WHERE artists_url = %s""", (content_names.encode('utf-8'),row[0]))
    row = mainDB_cursor.fetchone()


# Commit the transaction
mainDB_cnx.commit()

# Close the cursor
mainDB_cursor.close()


# Close the database connection
mainDB_cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the same cursor to execute more SQL while you still need the first result set:

```
with mainDB_cnx:
    mainDB_cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE Content.Reddit
        SET artists_names_2 = %s
        WHERE artists_url = %s""", (content_names.encode('utf-8'),row[0]))
```

That's going to replace the result set from the `SELECT` - yes, even though it's an `UPDATE`.